# Thread not starting?

Tags: java

Im working on a project and is confused at why the thread wont start when I call .start()

```
    int count = 0;

    while (count < urls.length) {
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new read(urls[count]));
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        count++;
    }
```

but if I add

```
public void start() {
     run();
}
```

in the read class and change the code to

```
    int count = 0;

    while (count < urls.length) {
        try {
            read thread =  new read(urls[count]);
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        count++;
    }
```

it works fine.

EDIT : here is my read class code
its reading data from url and calling some other methods i have in the class to store data etc.

```
    public class read implements Runnable {

    URL url;

    public read(String str) throws IOException {
        url = new URL(str); 
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

            String input;
            String[] temp;
            int x = 0;

            while (x < 10) {
                reader.readLine();
                x++;
            }

            while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                temp = input.split(" ");
                temp[2].replaceAll("<br>", "");
                String name = temp[0];
                int flightNum = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
                String des = temp[2];

                if (Airport.containsKey(flightNum) != true) {
                    addFlight(flightNum, des);
                    addPassengerReservation(flightNum, name);
                }
                else {
                    addPassengerReservation(flightNum, name);
                }

            }
            reader.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

Comment: Get rid of your `start` method, it's not how a `Thread` should be started. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: how do you know it does not start? What's your `read` class doing?

Comment: Also catching `Exception` with an empty catch block is a very, very bad idea. For all you know, the JVM could be trying to tell you what went wrong by throwing an `Exception`, and you are ignoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.start()` code registers the Thread with scheduler and the scheduler calls the `run()` method.You need to override the `run()` method.No need to call `run()` implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a class implementing Runnable (ClassA), and override the

```
public void run()
```

method.  From your "main" program, you should call:

```
Thread th = new Thread(new ClassA());
th.start();
```

You should never override the start method, or call `th.run()`.  Calling the start method will do some "behind the scenes" work, then call your `Runnable` Object's `run()` method for you.